# Check latest div

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

Is there a way to check the last added div?

I want to know this because I'm making a chat application with socket.io and bootstrap.

I'm new to using javascript and jquery. If I sent a message, and the latest message was also from me, I want my text to append to the panel I'm using.

Like this : [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn9rp.png)

Hopefully someone know's this.

Thanks in advance!

Code :

```
socket.on('newmsg', function (data) {
    if (user) {
        if (data.user == user) {
            document.getElementById('message-container').innerHTML += '\
            <div class="row">\
                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>\
                <div class="col-lg-5">\
                    <div class="panel panel-success">\
                        <div class="panel-heading">'+data.user+'</div>\
                        <div class="panel-body">\
                            <div class="row">\
                                <div class="col-lg-10">\
                                    '+data.message+'\
                                </div>\
                                <div class="col-lg-2">\
                                    '+data.time+'\
                                </div>\
                             </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
            </div> \
            ';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('message-container').innerHTML += '\
            <div class="row">\
                <div class="col-lg-6"></div>\
                <div class="col-lg-5">\
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">\
                        <div class="panel-heading">'+data.user+'</div>\
                        <div class="panel-body">\
                            <div class="row">\
                                <div class="col-lg-10">\
                                    '+data.message+'\
                                </div>\
                                <div class="col-lg-2">\
                                    '+data.time+'\
                                </div>\
                             </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
            </div> \
            ';
        }

    }
})
```

Comment: Show some code what you have tried.

Comment: You haven't shown any code so it's hard to give you a definitive answer, but you could use the `:last` selector to find the final element contained within a parent, eg `$('#chat-messages .message:last')`. I'd suggest you read the documentation to see what you can then do with that element: http://api.jquery.com

Comment: Here is the code to add a new message @AtaurRahmanMunna Now i want to check the last panel header text to check if the last message was from me or the other person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append your div element with message at last by using `jquery`

```js
var addedText = '<div> this is second message</div>';
$('#msgGroup > div').last().append(addedText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="msgGroup">
    <div>this is first msg</div>
</div>
```

See the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ld1a79d3/) also.

Answer (score -1):

https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/
Read this.
You can use $("div:last")

```js
    $("div.panel-body div.row:last").css("color","red")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <html>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">First row</div>
    <div class="row">Second row</div>
    </div>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can i also get all the info of that div with that function? Like the panel header text

Comment: @BharatPatidar What chat app have you seen where messages get added to the middle of the chat log?

Comment: I want to make it look like my own whatsapp web